comparision block not working on plpgsql. Comparing text
i have the following plpgsql function:
CREATE or replace TRIGGER conteo_nulls
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON public.datos
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION conteo_nulls();





create or replace function conteo_nulls() returns trigger as $$
declare
c INT;
rescrape bool := false;
feriado_ bool := false;
dia text;
begin
    SELECT count(*) into c FROM public.datos where fundseries is null and scrap_date=new.scrap_date group by scrap_date;
    if c > 5 then
        rescrape := true;
    end if;
    dia := TO_CHAR(new.scrap_date, 'Day');
    RAISE NOTICE 'El día de la semana es: %', pg_typeof(TO_CHAR(new.scrap_date::DATE, 'Day'));
    **---THIS IF BLOCK NOT ENTER.
    if dia::TEXT = 'Sunday' or dia::TEXT = 'Saturday'::TEXT then
        RAISE NOTICE '****estoy dentro del if variable feriado es : %', feriado;
        feriado_ := true;
    end if;
    --END BLOCK
    **
    RAISE NOTICE 'estoy fuera del if variable feriado es : %', feriado_;
    insert into datos_resume values(new.scrap_date,c,rescrape,dia,feriado_);
RETURN NEW;
end;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

But on the second IF block, it not enter. Both text are 'Sunday', but the comparision not working. it is comparing "Sunday"="Sunday" but it do not enter inside the if block and do not switch from false to true.
Could you helpme what i am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.


In psql do a select TO_CHAR('2024-04-28'::date, 'Day') and see what you get. 2) Is scrap_date actually a date type or a timestamp(tz) type?


It's easier to use DOW, Day Of Week: EXTRACT(DOW from new.scrap_date) = 0 for Sunday.

The rest of your function has problems, too. Like: RETURN NEW in an AFTER trigger does nothing useful. Or you raise both notices on weekends, but I guess you just want one. Or INSERT without target columns ...

Your issue is that to_char(<date>, 'Day') returns a fixed length value of 9 characters, blanked padded on the right as required needed.  You can either pad the target value or trin the result of to_char().  (see demo)
So something like:
create or replace function conteo_nulls() returns trigger as $$
declare
c INT;
rescrape bool := false;
feriado_ bool := false;
dia text;
begin
    SELECT count(*) into c FROM public.datos where fundseries is null and scrap_date=new.scrap_date group by scrap_date;
    if c > 5 then
        rescrape := true;
    end if;
    dia := trim(TO_CHAR(new.scrap_date, 'Day'));    --<< Changed here >> 
    RAISE NOTICE 'El día de la semana es: %', pg_typeof(TO_CHAR(new.scrap_date::DATE, 'Day'));
     
    if dia::TEXT = 'Sunday' or dia::TEXT = 'Saturday'::TEXT then
        RAISE NOTICE '****estoy dentro del if variable feriado es : %', feriado;
        feriado_ := true;
    end if;
    
    RAISE NOTICE 'estoy fuera del if variable feriado es : %', feriado_;
    insert into datos_resume values(new.scrap_date,c,rescrape,dia,feriado_);
RETURN NEW;
end;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

